# How to programmatically get header information of dataset from UCI data repository in R

Tags: r, dataset

I am trying to collect publicly available [datasets from UCI repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html) for **R**. I understand there are lots of datasets already usable with several **R** packages such as `mlbench.` But there are still several datasets I will need from UCI repository.

This is a trick I learned

```
url="http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/credit-screening/crx.data"
credit<-read.csv(url, header=F)
```

But this does not get header (variable name) information. That information is in [*.names](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/credit-screening/crx.names) file in text format. Any idea how I can programmatically get header information as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you'll have to use regular expressions to accomplish this. Here's an ugly, but general solution that should work on a variety of *.names files, assuming their formats are similar to the one you posted.

```
names.file.url <-'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/credit-screening/crx.names' 
names.file.lines <- readLines(names.file.url)

# get run lengths of consecutive lines containing a colon.
# then find the position of the subgrouping that has a run length 
# equal to the number of columns in credit and sum the run lengths up 
# to that value to get the index of the last line in the names block.
end.of.names <- with(rle(grepl(':', names.file.lines)), 
                       sum(lengths[1:match(ncol(credit), lengths)]))

# extract those lines
names.lines <- names.file.lines[(end.of.names - ncol(credit) + 1):end.of.names]

# extract the names from those lines
names <- regmatches(names.lines, regexpr('(\\w)+(?=:)', names.lines, perl=TRUE))

# [1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "A4"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A8"  "A9"  "A10" "A11"
# [12] "A12" "A13" "A14" "A15" "A16"
```

Comment: @Thomas, sorry. I usually try to avoid writing stuff that looks magical. Short on time right now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `Attribute Information` must be the names in the specific file you pointed. Here is a very, very dirty solution to do that. I use a fact that there is a pattern - your names are followed by `:` so we separte the strings of characters by `:` using `scan`, and then grab names from raw vector:

```
url="http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/credit-screening/crx.data"
credit<-read.csv(url, header=F)
url.names="http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/credit-screening/crx.names"
mess <- scan(url.names, what="character", sep=":")
#your names are located from 31 to 61, every second place in the vector
mess.names <- mess[seq(31,61,2)]
names(credit) <- mess.names
```

Comment: Actually variable names in this case are `A1`,...`A16.` But I get the gist of what you are saying. Thanks

Comment: @Thomas Ok, kind of makes sense, I corrected my answer, but it's not as universal as you probably want..